# Cypher: Batch deleting all relationships for a specific relationship if there are more than one for a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The issue I am working through is trying to figure out how the best way to go about doing the following is.
Problem: I have node A that may either have 0, 1, or multiple outgoing relationships to node B.
However, I want all nodes to either have 0 or only 1 outgoing relationship to B at a time.
I need to figure out what an efficient way of of deleting all relationships for all node A's that have more than 1 outgoing relationship to node B.

While the bottom code snippet has been fine for deleting ALL the outgoing relationships for a specific relationship across ALL node A's

```
    call apoc.periodic.iterate(
        'MATCH (a: DataA)-[r: RELATIONSHIP_NAME]->(b: DataB) RETURN id(r) AS id',
        'MATCH (a: DataA)-[r: RELATIONSHIP_NAME]->(b: DataB) WHERE id(r)=id DELETE r',
        {batchSize: 10000}
    )
```

Referencing: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/large-delete-transaction-best-practices-in-neo4j/

I have been having issues trying to alter it to include all ids for a relationship for only nodes where there are multiple for a node and having that then pass those submultiple relationship ids for each node to delete.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to delete all relationships except one.

```
MATCH (a:A)
WITH [(a)-[r]->(:B) | r] AS rs
WHERE SIZE(rs) > 1

UNWIND rs[1..] AS r
DELETE r
```